# syntax for comparing values

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone know what is wrong with following code?:
I have extra parenthesis to compare the  difference in value!

```
(Sheet1.Cells(i - 1, "H").Value - Sheet1.Cells(i, "H").Value) < 60 / 86400
```

Comment: Is this part of an IF statement?  It is incomplete. What is the value of `i`?

Comment: This is full if statement:If  `Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = "A" And Sheet1.Cells(i - 1, "B").Value = "D" And Sheet1.Cells(i - 1, "H").Value - Sheet1.Cells(i, "H").Value < 60 / 86400 Then`  Sorry I don't know how to edit original question!

Comment: we need to see the rest of your code, it's almost impossible to find the possible cause to your error

Comment: If `i` has a value of anything less than 2, it will error.

Comment: Great thanks. I just changes the `i` counter to 3 and its working fine. Thanks alot